# Starting function after applying migrations

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I have a function, that set users online to 0 on starting server (users online is `int`. Increment on connecting to websocket and decrementing on disconnect).

```
def ready(self):
    from . import signals
    from .models import UserAccount
    UserAccount.objects.filter(online__gt=0).update(online=0)
```

That starts on app ready, but I've got some troubles: when my remote mirror downloaded sources from repo, this function has been worked before migrations was applied, and column `online` doesn't exists this time, and server goes to perpetual reboot.

I may have other functions, that should be run before after accepting migrations.

How to run this code after migrations will be applied?

Comment: Didn't get what exactly you trying to achieve. If you just want your code to run after migrations are applied you can use `post_migrate` signal `from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate`.
is that what you want?

Comment: @xxbinxx yeah, it's literally what i need. But earlier I thought it was only suitable for a specific model. Not for all app
Does is it works when i haven't migrations to apply?

Comment: @xxbinxx *that set users online to 0 on starting server* would it work in that case?

Comment: @NafeesAnwar Never actually tried signals directly with apps but it should work. 
```def ready(self):
        signals.post_migrate.connect(my_custom_method, sender=self, weak=False)```

check the [post migrate documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#post-migrate)

Comment: @xxbinxx is it will work only on startup? I don't need to do this if i'll migrate manually, when server is up.

Comment: If you want to run code everytime just before migrations apply use [pre_migrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#pre-migrate) and similarly if you want to run code everytime after migrations are applied, use `post_migrate`

Comment: @Ingwar it's not for startup. It's when the migrations are applied.